Did Professor X’s school have non-superhero students in the early days?
In The Uncanny X-Men vol. 1 #178, narration describes Professor X and his school. A caption reads, “Here, he teaches his pupils how to control those abilities, that they may better survive in a society that at best mistreats -- and at worst, hates -- them, simply because they exist. A very select few join his team of unsung, occasionally outlaw super-heroes -- the uncanny X-Men.“
“A very select few” suggests that he has many students that don’t go on to join the X-Men. But at the point of this issue’s publication, as far as I can tell, every student who has been enrolled at his school has gone on to to join the X-Men (other than the five or six New Mutants, who at the time of this issue’s publication, had only recently debuted).
My question is, had it ever been established, before this point, that Professor X had other non-superhero students at his school? And at what point does this begin to be shown more deliberately?

There's a bunch of students (like Illyana Rasputina and Roberto Da Costa) who aren't X-Men when we join them (as early as UX-M: 188). It's something of a selection bias that anyone important enough to merit a name will eventually become an X-Men.

To phrase what I’m asking in another way: are there students at his school who we just don’t see because they’re not important to the X-Men/New Mutants story? Based on the quote in my post, it seems like that’s the intention, but it’s weird that we’ve seemingly never seen a single one of them up to that point

I'm just working my way through the Uncanny X-Men to find the first time we see a mundane classroom with some non-descript mutants being tutored.
